# Get Checked RadioButtons using JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, html, function, windows-runtime

so I’m trying to build a win 8 app, which includes a WebView. The WebView contains the HTML code (+JavaScript) below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC " -//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' >

<script type='text/javascript'>
function get_radio_value()
{
  for (var i=0; i < document.myForm.frage1.length; i++)
  {
    if (document.orderform.frage1[i].checked)
    {
          var rad_val = document.myForm.frage1[i].value;
          return rad_val;
    }
  }
}
</script>

    <title>Kundenfragebogen</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Kundenfragebogen</h1>
<div id='myDiv'>Hello</div>
<form name='myForm' action=''>
<table border='2'>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>sehr gut</td>
    <td>gut</td>
    <td>schlecht</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wie geht es Ihnen?</td>
    <td><input type='radio' name="frage1" value='1'/>Mir ging es noch nie besser!</td>
    <td><input type='radio' name="frage1" value='2'/>Es geht mir so wie immer.</td>
    <td><input type='radio' name="frage1" value='3'/>Heute geht einfach gar nichts…</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Können Sie Auto fahren?</td>
    <td><input type='radio' name="frage2" value='1'/>Ja</td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type='radio' name="frage2" value='3'/>Nein</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Möchten Sie unseren Newsletter abonnieren?</td>
    <td><input type='radio' name="frage3" value='1'/>Ja</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type='button' value='Formular absenden' onclick="return get_radio_value()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So the html contains some radio buttons and a button. I’ve used JavaScript ~2 years ago (just a little), so I don’t really know how to write the exact code. I’ve found something on the internet, but it doesn’t do what I want. I want to have the following:

The user can check the RadioButtons. When the user clicks the Button, the JavaScript function should return all the checked radio buttons (I only need to know which RadioButton is checked).
Since I know the name of the RadioButtons in my Windows 8 App, I can do the following:

```
var object = WebView.InvokeScript("JavaScriptFunctionNAME", NameOfRadiobutton);
```

So the WebView invokes the script and should get as a return the VALUE of the RadioButton, which is checked.

“JavaScriptFunctionNAME” = name of the function in Javascript

NameOfRadiobutton = the name of the RadioButton as a parameter (for example “frage1”).

Currently I’m returning the value of the radiobutton, which is checked in the RadioGroup “frage1”. How can I check every RadioButton by it’s parameter? By this I mean I have a parameter “frage1” and return the value of the checked RadioButton. After this, I call the function again with the parameter “frage2” and return the checked RadioButtons value. Could anyone help me out with the JavaScript-function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radiobuttons are grouped by their name property. You can get a collection of radiobuttons using `document.getElementsByName` and look at the checked status of each, for example: -

```
function FindChecked() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByName("frage1")
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].checked) {
            return elements[i].value;
        }
    }
}
```

Will return the value of the checked radiobutton within its group.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/aX2qd/13/)

Edit: To pass the group name from your C# code to this function you could do: -

```
public class YourClass
{
   public string GroupName { get { return "frage1"; } }
}
```

And then the javascript function would become:

```
function FindChecked() {
     var elements = document.getElementsByName('<%= this.GroupName %>')
     for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].checked) {
            return elements[i].value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to pass a parameter and get the value according to the parameter. With your function, I'd do function `FindChecked(RadioName)` and `var elements = document.getElementsByName(RadioName)` so I can pass the parameter in my C# program (for example 'frage1'), is the syntax correct or would this work? By the way, when I use InvokeScript, I can only pass an array of string to the JavaScript function.

Comment: Yes the syntax is correct. If you need to pass in the groupname from your C# code then you could use an inline server tag to pass the groupname to the javascript function e.g. `Function FindChecked('<%= groupName %>')`

Comment: Edited my answer to explain

Comment: By using InvokeScript, I can pass the name of the RadioButtons. Check this link to see what I mean: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/1251d330-ae51-4c31-a270-8a0faf50bfa1/webbrowserinvokescript-string-array-problem . "p_0" would be "frage1" and "p_1" would be "frage2". I would do a for-loop IN MY C# PROGRAM and call the JavaScript function with InvokeScript with 1 parameter, which always contains current the GroupName (which I get from the for-loop) of the RadioButton.

Comment: Always wondering why your function is not working... ";" is missing. I just need to pass the parameter now to the javascript function and that's it, but the function is doing what I want to have. Edit: using `FindChecked(rbname)` and `document.getElementsByName(rbname);` is working fine, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this , This will return the checked name of radio buttons

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function get_radio_value()
    {
       var nameArry = [];
        var allInputs = document.myForm.getElementsByTagName('input');
       for (i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {
           if (allInputs[i].type == 'radio' && allInputs[i].checked ) {
             nameArry.push(allInputs[i].name);
           }
       }
       alert(nameArry)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Edit my question. I'm returning the value of the RadioButton now, but only the value of the RadioButtons with the name "frage1". I want to do a for-loop in my C# program where I pass the name of the RadioButton by a parameter. By this I want to call the JavaScript-function and get the checked value of the RadioButton with the name of the passed parameter. Your solution gives me at the moment only the value of the RadioGroup-Name "frage1".